Unity apply button in fbx file is grayed out even after changes are made
In Unity, I've had imported my 3D character to the project and it was ok. Then I made a new animation in blender and exported my character again as FBX, replaced the file in unity project folder and now when I add the new animation in Animation tab inside the inspector of the fbx file, the 'Apply' button doesn't activate and does not let me save the changes. Even when I make other changes to the file, the appy button doesn't get activated. When i click on another file and then click on the


So I've found the problem just before hitting the post button.
The inspector window was on 'Debug' mode which prevented me from applying the changes. After changing it back to 'Normal', it allowed me to save changes.

